# Mean of a PMF with a variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am given the following `PMF`:

[image]

and I am asked to find the `mean`. I'm a bit lost on what to do with the `k` from my understanding the mean would be x * probablity so if there was no k it would be -1(2) + 0(.5)+1(3) or something like that?

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total values of $f(x)$ should add up to $1$ in a probability distribution function.

Thus, $2k + 0.5 + 3k = 1$

Solve for $k$, then use the value for $k$ to determine the mean $E[X]=\sum_x xf(x)$ where the sum ranges over $x \in \{ -1, 0 , 1 \}$.

Comment: so k = 0.1, but is E(x) the same thing as the mean?

Comment: yeah, e(x) stands for expected value, another word for mean

Comment: so -1(.2) + 0(.5) + 1(.3)?

Comment: could you also explain how to find the variance?

Comment: have you been introduced to the general formula for variance before? $e(x^2) - e(x)^2$

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for your help!